# Pontiac Grand Prix white smoke

Tags: pontiac, smoke, grand-prix

I have a 1998 Pontiac Grand Prix with 108,000 miles on it it was running fine for 2 weeks and then it throwed a P0300 code and then it throwed a P0446 code. When it through the P0446 code it was running real rough and smoke was coming out a lot and it would barely run. I was told that I may have a head gasket leak or intake gasket leak but there is no coolant in the oil or oil in the coolant. There is something in the engine motor oil it is the level is way high and I am low on transmission fluid. Trying to figure out why her how transmission fluid got in the motor oil this may be why it's blowing white smoke.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What engine does this have in it? Is it the naturally aspirated 3.1L, 3.8L, or Supercharged 3.8L?

Comment: 3.1 motor naturally aspirated